# jQuery Selectors-> How can I get the value of a field that was selected with 'id begins/ends with'?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am attempting to get the value of a select field, but .val() does not appear to be working.

I get the select field by using begins and ends with.

```
s_day = $("select[id ^='form-widgets'][id $='start-day']")
```

I open a form and it finds a field:

```
if(s_day.length > 0){
    console.log(s_day[0]);
}
```

console.log outputs

```
<select class="day date-widget required date-field" name="form.widgets.entry_start-day" id="form-widgets-entry_start-day">
```

When I try:

```
console.log(s_day[0].val())
```

I get:

```
s_day[0].val is not  a function
```

When I try entering the return field's id manually:

```
s_day = $("#form-widgets-IEventBasic-start-day");
console.log(s_day.val());
```

It returns the day of the month (as an integer).

How can I get the val of the select box with the method I was using?

There is a reason why I am trying to do this.  Certain forms have 'interfaces' with the start/end fields with the field ids matching the pattern select[id ^='form-widgets'][id $='start-day'] 
There's also -month, -year, etc.
And I want to target those to change their default values.

What I could do for now is something along the lines of:

```
s_day = $('select[id ^="form-widgets"][id $="start-day"]');
if(s_day.length > 0){
    console.log($("#"+s_day[0].id).val());
}
```

This returns the day of the month correctly as well.

But I'm not sure if I should approach that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the jQuery object by index returns the underlying DOM Element, hence the 'val is not a function' error.

If you want to retrieve the first found element, use `first()` or `:first`, like this:

```js
var s_day = $('select[id^="form-widgets"][id$="start-day"]:first').val();

console.log(s_day);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="day date-widget required date-field" name="form.widgets.entry_start-day" id="form-widgets-entry_start-day">
  <option value="foo">Foo</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I appreciate it.  I have a better understanding of the selector.